Обращение к основному файлу из пакета
Помогите разобраться, как правильно указать запрос, чтобы при такой структуре обратиться из file.py к основному файлу main.py в корневой директории:
/Project
    /Package 
        __init__.py
        file.py
    main.py

Не могу понять как правильно и получаю ошибку: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
P.S.
Функции в классе Main отвечающие за отрисовку tree и обновление при нажатии на кнопку обновить (update_tree):
def create_tree_widget(self, bd: list = None):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_use('winnative')
        style.configure('mystyle.Treeview.Heading', font=('Times New '
                                                          'Roman', 14, 'bold'))
        style.configure('mystyle.Treeview', font=('Times New Roman', 14))
        
        self.rowconfigure(index=2, weight=2)
        self.columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
        columns = ('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3', 'column_4', 'column_5')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=columns, show='headings', style='mystyle.Treeview')
        self.tree.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.tree.heading('column_1', text='#', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('column_2', text='Автор', anchor='center', command=lambda: self.update_tree(bd=select_book.request_sort('author')))
        self.tree.heading('column_3', text='Название книги', anchor='center', command=lambda: self.update_tree(bd=select_book.request_sort('title')))
        self.tree.heading('column_4', text='Состояние', anchor='center', command=lambda: self.update_tree(bd=select_book.request_sort('state')))
        self.tree.heading('column_5', text='Статус', anchor='center')

        width_column_2, width_column_3 = select_book.request_max_len()

        self.tree.column('#1', stretch=tk.NO, width=40, anchor='center')
        self.tree.column('#2', stretch=tk.NO, width=width_column_2*9,
                         anchor='ne')
        self.tree.column('#3', stretch=tk.NO, width=width_column_3*10)
        self.tree.column('#4', stretch=tk.NO, width=110, anchor='center')
        self.tree.column('#5', stretch=tk.NO, width=80, anchor='center')

        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ns')

        for item in bd:
             self.tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4],)

        self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', self.item_selected)

        return self.tree

def update_tree(self, bd: list = None):
        [self.tree.delete(i) for i in self.tree.get_children()]
        self.tree = self.create_tree_widget(bd)

Функция в классе Main создающая главное меню, кнопки в котором ссылаются на функции в package:
def create_main_menu(self):
        menu = tk.Menu()
        menu.add_cascade(label='Обновить', command=self.update_tree)
        menu.add_cascade(label='Добавить книгу', command=self.btn_add)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        self.option_add('*tearOff', tk.FALSE)
        return menu

Функции в классе Package:
def __init__(self):
        self.add_window = tk.Toplevel()
        self.add_window.title('Добавить')
        window_center.center(self.add_window)
        self.create_window()

def create_window(self):
        label_author = ttk.Label(self.add_window, text='Автор:',
                                 font=('Georgia', 14))
        label_author.place(x=66, y=20)
        self.entry_author = ttk.Entry(self.add_window, font=('Georgia', 14), width=30)
        self.entry_author.place(x=140, y=20)

        label_title = ttk.Label(self.add_window, text='Название:',
                                font=('Georgia', 14))
        label_title.place(x=34, y=60)
        self.entry_title = ttk.Entry(self.add_window, font=('Georgia', 14), width=30)
        self.entry_title.place(x=140, y=60)

btn_submit = ttk.Button(self.add_window, text='Добавить книгу',
                                command=self.action)
        btn_submit.place(x=260, y=218)

def action(self):
        author = self.entry_author.get()
        title = self.entry_title.get()
insert_book.request(author, title)
self.add_window.destroy()

Как мне выполнить обновление update_tree в классе Main, после выполнение функций в классе Package?


По идее никак, в ошибке всё написано, нельзя из пакета куда-то выше обращаться. Эдак вы может вообще захотите в c:\windows залезть или ещё куда-то, куда не следует )  2) Сама архитектура, когда вам из нижних пакетов нужно обращаться куда-то наверх выглядит неправильной. Вы должны пакеты через main диспетчерить между собой, а не ходить из библиотек куда-то вдруг наверх, в тот же main. 3) Я могу быть в чём-то неправ, конечно )


@CrazyElf можете подсказать тогда направление, не могу понять ибо - есть Main класс приложения в котором дерево с записями tree_view и оно обновляется функцией внутри этого класса. Main класс внутри себя обращается к Package из которого загружает отображение кнопок и их функций внутри себя. Вот только как обновлять tree_view после выполнения функций из Package если нажимается кнопка - я не соображу. Хотел из пакета обращаться к классу Main и вызывать его функцию обновления. Ибо там параметр self, который есть у Main..

Вам не класс сам нужен, а объект. Объект можно передать через параметры функций, например. Импорт для этого не нужен, тем более что у вас циклический импорт получится, если main импортирует file, а file импортирует main.

Без конкретного кода сложно что-то советовать. Но в общих чертах должно быть так: в main вы импортируете нужные классы и функции из пакетов, инстанциируете классы, вызываете функции, всё делаете в main. Зачем вам обратный вызов из пакета в main - я пока не понял. Код хоть и находится физически в пакете, но выполняться то будет в main, контроль управления в нём. Если нужно, чтобы какая-то функция main вызвалась из кода пакета - передаёте ссылку на эту функцию при вызове кода пакета, и он, ничего не зная про main, просто дёргает то, что ему передали. Хотя такое вообще редко нужно.

@CrazyElf добавил основные куски кода для понимания, можете подсказать, как это возможно правильно связывать?

Так а где у вас инстанциируется класс Package? По-хорошему его нужно инстанциировать в main и тогда можно передать из main в конструктор Package ссылку на функцию, которую он будет вызывать в нужный момент, если этот момент зависит от этого класса. Хотя всё-таки по-хорошему UI лучше не дробить на разные пакеты и классы, в классы можно выносить бизнес-логику, а UI лучше когда весь в одном пакете лежит всё-таки.

Общий принцип -- "Внедрение зависимости" (IoC, DI). Используется постоянно, и для UI. В больших проектах без него вообще никак.
